# Take next parameter as field width in String.Format

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

In C#, I have a width I want to use for some strings, but I won't know that width until runtime.  I'm doing something like this:

```
string.Format("{0, " + digits + "}", value)  // prints 123 as "  123"
```

Is there a string formatting directive that lets me specify this without smashing my own format string together like this?

I looked around on MSDN for a little while and I feel like I'm missing a whole chapter on format strings or something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at `PadLeft`:

```
s = "123".PadLeft(5);  // Defaults to spaces
s = "123".PadLeft(5, '.');  // Pads with dots
```

Comment: i'll +1 you, because im embarrassed i forgot about padleft, it was on the tip of my tounge.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `PadLeft` and `PadRight` methods:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like

```
string test = valueString.PadLeft(10,' ');
```

or even sillier

```
string spaces = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(" ", digits).ToArray());
```

Comment: hahah i know, its pretty funny that i missed padleft, i found it as soon as i wrote that.

Answer (score 2):

The functions mentioned by others will work, but this MSDN page has a more general solution to formatting that changes at runtime:

[Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)

They give examples much like yours.

**Edit:** I thought you were trying to solve the general case of composing a format string at runtime. For example, if there were no built in PadLeft(), you could do this:

```
    int myInt = 123;
    int nColumnWidth = 10;

    string fmt = string.Format("Price = |{{0,{0}}}|", nColumnWidth);

    // now fmt = "Price = |{0,5}|"

    string s = string.Format(fmt, myInt);
```

You can even do all that in one line, but it's ugly:

```
    string s = string.Format(
            string.Format("Price = |{{0,{0}}}|", nColumnWidth),
            myInt);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm blind but I'm not seeing any example on that page that does something quite like what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help with your research on formatting:

[Formatting Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxft59x.aspx)

[Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)

However, I don't think you're going to do much better than this, as the alignment parameter must be part of the format string and does not seem to be represented by a property.

Comment: If "the alignment param must be part of the format string", that answers my question: it's not possible from string.Format.  I figured there would be some way to use params, like `(format nil "~vD" digits value)` in Lisp -- I know Lisp's `format` is a lot more powerful in general, but I figured using a param was basic enough.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably overkill but just to illustrate a way to encapsulate the format specification and use an overload of `String.Format` that accepts an `IFormatProvider`.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int digits = 7;
        var format = new PaddedNumberFormatInfo(digits);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(format, "{0}", 123));
    }
}
class PaddedNumberFormatInfo : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public PaddedNumberFormatInfo(int digits)
    {
        this.DigitsCount = digits;
    }

    public int DigitsCount { get; set; }

    // IFormatProvider Members
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;

        return null;
    }
    // ICustomFormatter Members
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return String.Format(
            String.Concat("{0, ", this.DigitsCount, "}"), arg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted a CodeProject article that may be what you want.

See: [A C# way for indirect width and style formatting.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403499/A-Csharp-way-for-indirect-width-and-style-formatti)

Basically it is a method, FormatEx, that acts like String.Format, except it allows for indirect alignment and formatString specifiers.

```
FormatEx("{0,{1}:{2}}", value, width, formatString);
```

Means format the value of varArgs 0, in a field width specified by varArgs 1, using a formattingString code specified by varArgs 2.

Edit: Internally, it does what many others have suggested in their answers.  I've just wrapped the parsing and determination of the final values to use for alignment and formatString.  I also added a "center alignment" modifier.

-Jesse

Answer (score 0):

`String` has a constructor that creates a string with a given character repeated `n` times.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx

```
// prints 123 as "  123"
string.Format(new string(' ', digits) + "{0}", value)
```