# How can I dynamically set the field width in c#

Tags: c#

I want to be able to set the field width dynamically, depending on the string length.

Here's my code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names = { "Adam", "Ron", "Carla", "Daniel", "Farla", "Marrietta" };
        decimal[] hours = { 40, 6.667M, 40.39M, 82, 40.333M, 80 };

        var sorted = names.OrderBy(n => n.Length);
        int longest = sorted.LastOrDefault().Length + 1;

        Console.WriteLine($"{"Name", longest} {"Hours",5}\n");
        for(var ctr = 0; ctr < names.Length; ctr++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{names[ctr],longest} {hours[ctr],5:N1}");
        }

    }
```

I'm getting an error that constant value is expected 'instead of' longest.

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take next parameter as field width in String.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314320/take-next-parameter-as-field-width-in-string-format)

Comment: The error is caused by your incorrect usage of string interpolation ($). It is not clear what you want to print in each loop. In any case sorting the names array doesn't sort also the hours array. If you want to keep the tow values together you need to use an array containing a custom class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string.Format()` (and accordingly string interpolation) needs constant values for these formats.

You can use [`string.PadLeft()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk6ydzx(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
for(var ctr = 0; ctr < names.Length; ctr++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{names[ctr].PadLef(longest)} {hours[ctr],5:N1}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code fails because iterpolation does not allow a variable in the field-width expression

try using string.PadRight instead:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{  
    string[] names = new string[] { "Adam", "Ron", "Carla", "Daniel", "Farla", "Marrietta" };
    decimal[] hours = { 40, 6.667M, 40.39M, 82, 40.333M, 80 };

    var sorted = names.OrderBy(n => n.Length);
    int longest = sorted.LastOrDefault().Length + 1;

    //Console.WriteLine($"{"Name", longest} {"Hours",5}\n");
    for(var ctr = 0; ctr < names.Length; ctr++)
    {
        string msg = String.Format("{0} {1,5:N1}", names[ctr].PadRight(longest), hours[ctr]);
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

}
```